# What are the benefits of Azure Static Website Hosting over Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Just read this article about Static website hosting in Azure Storage :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website.

For the moment, I use to deploy my static content to [Azure CDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cdn/).

So far here are the difference that I've found:

- Network performance
- Pricing
- Custom 404 page (Azure Static Website Hosting)
- Custom DNS is only supported for Azure CDN ???

I am wondering what could be a good candidate for Static website hosting in Azure Storage:

Content for local application that does not need to scale globally ?

Answer (score 3):

As the official said, the benefits of using Azure CDN to deliver web site assets include:

1. Better performance and improved user experience for end users, especially when using applications in which multiple round-trips are required to load content.
2. Large scaling to better handle instantaneous high loads, such as the start of a product launch event.
3. Distribution of user requests and serving of content directly from edge servers so that less traffic is sent to the origin server.

**I don't think that host Static website in Azure Storage is a good candidate because of the performance. Below points show the features of CDN which are what Azure Storage do not have:**

1. CDN is a content distribution network built on the network. It relies on the edge servers deployed everywhere, through the load balancing, content distribution, scheduling and other functional modules of the central platform, so that users can get the required content near the network, reduce network congestion, improve the user's access response speed and hit rate. The key technologies of CDN include content storage and distribution technology.
2. The basic principle of CDN is that various caching servers are widely used to distribute the caching servers to areas or networks which are relatively centralized by users. When users access the web site, the user's access is directed to the nearest working normal cache server using the global load technology, and the cache server is used directly. The household request.
3. Content distribution network (CDN) is a new network construction method, which is specially optimized for the distribution of broadband media in traditional IP networks, and from a broad sense, CDN represents a network service model based on quality and order.
4. Simply speaking, content distribution network (CDN) is a strategic deployment of the overall system, including distributed storage, load balancing, network request redirection and content management 4 elements, and content management and the global network traffic management (Traffic Management) is the core of the CDN. Through the judgement of user proximity and server load, CDN ensures that the content provides services for users' requests in a highly efficient way.

In general, content services are based on caching servers, also known as proxy caches (Surrogate), which are located on the edge of the network and are only "one hop" (Single Hop) away from the user. At the same time, proxy caching is a transparent image of the content provider source server (usually located in the data center of the CDN service provider). Such an architecture allows CDN service providers to represent their customers, the content providers, to provide the best possible experience to the end users, which can not tolerate any delay in the response time of the request.

More information about CDN, we can refer to: [Content Delivery Network and its Business Benefits](http://www.ctrls.in/blog/content-delivery-network-and-its-business-benefits/)

In addition, custom DNS is not only for CDN: [Setting up Custom DNS Records to point to Azure Web Sites - with Stefan Schackow](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/videos/custom-dns-records-with-azure-web-sites/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but sorry this does not quite answer my question. I know benefits of CDN but with this new feature, I am wondering when I should use it. I dont think microsoft build useless new feature :-) Maybe it is just easier to deploy

Comment: @Thomas Azure CDN is a commercial products which will create profits for the Microsoft. This is why Microsoft build this new feature. Azure CDN has all the advantages of CDN. So when you need to speed up your web site, you can choose this new feature

Comment: In fact the new feature is `Azure Static website hosting` not Azure CDN

Comment: @Thomas can you put the static website behind the cdn?  I'm looking at setting this up and also looking at azure front door, which might provide the same benefits of cdn

Comment: Just use Azure CDN is you need one. My guess is that `Azure Static website hosting` acts as a CDn but in only one region